# How to select data from jsonb column?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have got one column with type jsonb. The data in this column looks as below

```
{
    "random_number1":
    {
        "random_number2":
        {
            "Param1": 2,
            "Param2": 0,
            "Param3": 0,
            "Param4": 6,
            "Param5": 3
        }
    }
}
```

How to write select for this column if I want f.e. all rows where "Param3"=6 ?
I tried something like that

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column->'Param3' @> '6'::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your expectations.

Get the value of a specified path:

```
select *
from my_table
where my_col->'random_number1'->'random_number2'->>'Param3' = '6'
```

Get the value of the key `Param3` of any object on the third level:

```
select t.*
from my_table t,
jsonb_each(my_col) as value1(key1, value1),
jsonb_each(value1) as value2(key2, value2)
where jsonb_typeof(my_col) = 'object'
and jsonb_typeof(value1) = 'object'
and value2->>'Param3' = '6';
```

In the second case you may want to use `distinct` as the query may yield duplicated rows.

Comment: The problem is that random_number1 and random_number2 are always different numeric values

Comment: Therefore you have two variants of the answer. Use the second one.

Comment: But in second case I got an error "cannot call jsonb_each on a non-object"

Comment: This means that you have a json structure different from that described in your question. You cannot use generic jsonb functions when the json structures differ in each row.

Comment: Sounds bad. Thank you anyway!

Comment: However, you can add some checks in `where` clause to guard against an error. See the updated answer.